# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) in marshmallow while upload image to server

Tags: android, image, upload, android-6.0-marshmallow

Im working on the project which i want to send image to server. When i send image to server all versions except marshmallow works fine.

I got the permission while pick the image from gallery. Is there is any I any special permission to send image ?

```
private static int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

            }
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain..? Why you Downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

IN Activity

```
  private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE = 112;


  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_STORAGE );
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

 /*get Permissions Result*/
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
               startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

   /*check permissions  for marshmallow*/

private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask runtime permissions for user. Check this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Check this example. http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/

Answer (score 1):

There is one more permission of Internet that might be missing to give.

```
"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />"
```

Also do go to settings and check if the permission has been granted as in marshmallow the permission is needed to be given at runtime..

Check below link....
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Hope your problem gets resolved with this...